# Starting Spark Session using Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm starting a Spark Session but I keep getting '**FileNotFound**' error with this information "**[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified**".

I tried to create a file where I saved my notebook but the error still persists.
Here is my code;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjWHL.png)
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Give us the actual code and error; do not post a picture.